# How can I use Vuex state array values in a vue component?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, getter

I have a `store.js` file that have the following state and getter:

```
state: {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    user: {}
},

getters: {
    getUserId: state => state.user.id
},
```

After a user is logged in, the `isLoggedIn` becomes true and `user` is populated with the user's info as seen in image below:

[image]

As you can see I have a getter, in the `store.js` that retrieves the correct ID but when I go to use this in my component, it comes up as `undefined`.

My component looks like this:

```
const id = this.$store.getters.getUserId;
console.log(id);
```

How can I use the value of `getUserId` in my component?

Comment: Where and when do you call `console.log(id)`? This is probably the real issue here (you may have it too early, when it's still undefined). To be sure, you could `console.log` it on a button `@click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I limit myself only to solving the problem based on the interpretation of the code provided

**Solution 1**:

> **const id = this.$store.getters.getUserId;** I agree with the comment (kissu), but well regardless of where: in a hook, a method... You can use mapGetters in a computed property. Import:
>
> > import {mapGetters} from 'vuex // add this line in your component

```
 <template>
...
 UserId: {{ getUserId }}
...
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex 
.
.
computed: {
   ...mapGetters(['getUserId']) // Also can use namespaces if preferred
}
...
</script>
```

**Solution 2**

> You can used directly in  DOM

```
<template>
...
 UserId: {{ $store.getters.getUserId }}
...
</template>
```

I hope it will be useful